# Ubuntu 20.04 focal - Input keyboard language

Tags: keyboard, language-support, input-language, japanese

I'm looking for a way to write in Japanese so with the various characters like hiragana, kanji ecc.. So i tried to put Japanese as input source but it didn't work. I also found some tutorials on internet but they refer at others distributions or older version of ubuntu. Could someone help with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution for my problem at this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JapaneseInput)!

I've put the solution here for who will have the same problem. I hope it will be usefull.

Comment: Right, you need an input method such as the one provided by the `ibus-mozc` package.